# Weird error during buy tokens with eth on ropsten and other testnets

Tags: solidity-0.6.x, uniswap

I get this error when executing swap token for ether on arb detection.

```
Error Message: execution reverted
(uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = IUniswapV2Pair(pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)).getReserves();
at 
getReserves()
at 
Opcode: [STATICCALL]
in 
0xbc03cf2c6443d9bb25c8fd9b701d9eb22f85f584
Opcode: [CALL]
in 
0xbc03cf2c6443d9bb25c8fd9b701d9eb22f85f584
```

In nodejs, the error response is:

```
err...Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x1c668xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "blockNumber": 8143875,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 922169,
  "from": "0xab3388xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "gasUsed": 922169,
  "logsBloom": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Since my buy token function in solidity works normally when I call it from truffle console, I was wondering what could be a likely cause.

Here is the buy token function:

```
function buyCryptoOnUniswap(uint256 etherCost , address cryptoToken) public payable returns (uint256) {
//address cryptoToken = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;

if(etherCost > address(this).balance){
    return 0;
}
 
    uint deadline = now + 300; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!

   
    uint[] memory amounts = usi.swapExactETHForTokens.value(etherCost)(0, getPathForETHToToken(cryptoToken), address(this), deadline);
    uint256 outputTokenCount = uint256(amounts[amounts.length - 1]);

    return outputTokenCount;
}
```

[Here is a typical transaction that depicts this.](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb33f025e1241021a3b7d6d955a04786c135c129ed4e48f532ca2d34ae9eea340)
I hope someone can clue me in on particular or likely causes of such.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

With guidance from @goodvibration, I found that the error seems to be from this portion of code instead:

```
   function buyCryptoOnKyber(uint256 etherCost , address cryptoToken) public payable returns(uint256){
    //address cryptoToken = 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa;
    if(etherCost > address(this).balance){
        return 0;
    }
    KyberNetworkProxyInterface proxy = getKyberExchange();
    ERC20 token = ERC20(cryptoToken);
      
        uint minRate;
        (, minRate) = proxy.getExpectedRate(ETH_TOKEN_ADDRESS, token, etherCost);
    
        //will send back tokens to this contract's address
        uint destAmount = proxy.swapEtherToToken.value(etherCost)(token, minRate);
    
        //send received tokens to destination address
       require(token.transfer(address(this), destAmount));
       
    
        // refund leftover ETH to user
        //msg.sender.call.value(address(this).balance)("");
    
    
    }
    
    function kyberToUniSwapArb(address fromAddress,address toAddress, uint ethAmount) public payable returns (uint256){
     
        uint256 cryptoAmountPurchased = buyCryptoOnKyber( ethAmount , fromAddress);
    
         sellCryptoOnUniswap(cryptoAmountPurchased , toAddress);
    
        }

function sellCryptoOnUniswap(uint256 cryptoQty , address cryptoToken) public payable returns(uint256){
///selling code
}
```

**EDIT**

Comment: Please share your function call (i.e., what parameters you are passing to this function).

Comment: The values are being passed from a lender's callback and it reverts before I can make anything tangible out of it. I however suspect it is a parametric issue as seen in this online debugger's output:

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/ropsten/0xcaa4e751492a26598ba3527c90a5fe2ad83a4cc2be88517349b04bba8a7ce3ef/debugger

Hope you can make something out of it

Comment: The transaction is to [this contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf976ea9110d718959e010a05dbefc25699cfcc72#code). Please verify it on Etherscan.

Comment: I cant verify it yet for reasons. Can I post the executeOperation callback instead since that is where the errors occur? executeOperation is where the issues occur.

Comment: Sure, but that's partial information, so not necessarily will others be able to help you with the problem.

Comment: Hi @goodvibration. Thanks again. I wish you could post an answer, even if a short one. You were right. The problem is not solved, but your initial hunch about the parameters been passed is the issue. So if you post a short answer along those lines, I will gladly accept it. I have to go and check why the zero value made it to the function in question.

Comment: How can I post an answer when you haven't even posted the partial information that you promised???

Comment: Tracked it! thanks a whole lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, it had nothing to do with even the executeOperation, but I will post the necessary portion as promised...for posterity's(lol) sake. I mean, so the question will be easily understood

Comment: Posted @goodvibration. The error was in the kyberToUniswap arb function. The function buyCryptoOnKyber does not return anything in its implementation, but I returned a uint256 from it and passed it to sellCryptoOnUniswap. Solidity hence defaulted the value passed to zero, most likely which caused the errors